# Estou com problemas com React Vision Camera, quando mudo de uma tela e abro a câmera novamente

Tags: react-native

Olá! quando eu abro a câmera na tab2 (do bottom tab navigator), a camera funciona corretamente, tira foto, salva foto etc... porém, se eu trocar de tela, quando não houver tirado uma foto, e voltar depois na câmera novamente, ela simplesmente fica toda preta, não tira foto, não funciona o flash e nem nada. Eu tenho que reiniciar o APP para voltar a funcionar novamente. E se eu tiro uma foto, deixo a foto parada que tirei, e troco de tela e volto na tela da câmera, ela funciona.
Só dá problemas quando a foto não foi tirada, parece que ela fecha, e não consegue abrir novamente automaticamente.

Código da parte lógica da câmera em questão:

```
function Tab2Screen() {
  const camera = useRef(null);
  const devices = useCameraDevices();
const [isSaved, setIsSaved] = useState(false);

  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(true);
  const [imageSource, setImageSource] = useState('');


  const [flashEnabled, setFlashEnabled] = useState(false);

  const toggleFlash = () => {
    setFlashEnabled(!flashEnabled);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getPermission() {
      const permission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
      console.log(`Camera permission status: ${permission}`);
      if (permission === 'denied') await Linking.openSettings();
    }
    getPermission();
  }, []);

  const capturePhoto = async () => {
    if (camera.current !== null) {
      const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto({ flash: flashEnabled ? 'on' : 'off' }); 
      setImageSource(photo.path);
      setShowCamera(false);
      console.log(photo.path);
    }
  };

  const saveToGallery = async () => {
    try {
      if (imageSource) {
        await CameraRoll.save(imageSource, { type: 'photo' });
        setIsSaved(true); 
        console.log('Foto salva na galeria!');
        
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Erro ao salvar a foto na galeria:', error);
    }
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSaved) {
      
      ToastAndroid.show('Foto salva na galeria!', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
      setIsSaved(false); 
    }
  }, [isSaved])

  const device = devices?.back;

  if (!device) {
    return <Text> Câmera não está disponível</Text>;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui arrumar, para quem estiver com o mesmo problema no futuro:

O problema principal tava relacionado ao  ciclo de vida dentro do componente Tab2. Para resolver isso, separei o código relacionado à inicialização e liberação da câmera em dois useEffects..

utilizando o hook useIsFocused do React Navigation, permite verificar se a tela está em foco ou não.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (showCamera && isFocused) {
    // Código para inicializar a câmera aqui
  }
}, [showCamera, devices, isFocused]);
```

criando outro useEffect, ele liberou a câmera quando o componente Tab2 for desmontado.

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if (camera.current) {
      camera.current.release();
    }
  };
}, []);
```

verificar também se o objeto camera.current não está nulo antes de iniciar a câmera novamente.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).